# Token de acceso para archivos de Google Cloud Storage

Tags: aws, google-cloud-platform, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

estoy subiendo unos vídeos a un proyecto de Google Cloud Storage, lo que quiero es algo como lo de Amazon, AWS Security Token Service (STS)
Quiero que el vídeo sólo pueda acceder con el token por x cantidad de minutos y que siempre me pida un token válido para acceder al contenido.
He buscado información para hacer eso con Cloud pero aún no encuentro nada de relevancia.

Tendría que cambiarme a AWS o qué solución me dan?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo tu caso de uso, entiendo que el feature de Google Cloud Storage que coincide mejor con tus requerimientos son las [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).

**Signed URLs** es un mecanismo de autenticación para buckets y objetos almacenados en GCS, que proporciona acceso the lectura y/o escritura con limitación de tiempo a cualquiera que posea la URL (sin la necesidad de disponer de una cuenta de Google para ello).

La documentación de Signed URLs incluye varios ejemplos que muestra cómo [crear Signed URLs con `gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-gsutil) o incluso [de forma programática](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program). Más concretamente, puedes utiliza el comando `gsutil signurl`, con los diferentes flags disponibles (más información en la [documentacion de `gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl)) para crearlas de manear sencilla. El flag `-d` te permite especificar la duración del vídeo.